# How to set up automated pages translation in google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, translation

I want to translate all french to english, and all spanish to russian. Can such thing to be done?

Answer (score 0):

There is [Google Translate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb) extension which can automatically translate pages to desired language. But only to one language. Hope it helped.